# mousemove | touchmove performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

### JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wz9ghpnc/

## Issue

Using: latest jQuery

Why this lagging to much on mobile devices? I'm really done with trying to optimize this.

How can I apply something like debounce / throttling? I tried to add setTimeout to move() function with 50 ms delay but that was laggy too.

Moving on mobile is so laggy... animations are too so laggy...

```
let $state = {
  afterDown: {
    clientX: 0,
    scrollLeft: 0,
  },
  afterUp: {
    clientX: 0,
    scrollLeft: 0,
  },
  dreamedScrollLeft: 0,
  isDown: false,
};

let centering = false;
let duration = 250;
let messages = false;

function message () {
  if (messages === true) {
    console.log('%c addScroll ', 'background: #000; color: #fff;', ...arguments);
  }
}

// Events

function down (parent) {
  return (event) => {
    message('down');

    if ($state.isDown === false) {
      $state.afterDown.clientX = event.originalEvent.touches ? event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX : event.clientX;
      $state.afterDown.scrollLeft = $(parent).scrollLeft();

      $(parent).stop();

      $state.isDown = true;
    }
  };
}

function leave (parent) {
  return () => {
    message('leave');

    if ($state.isDown === true) {
      $(parent).removeClass('scroll-moving');

      $state.isDown = false;
    }
  };
}

function move (parent) {
  return (event) => {
    message('move');

    if ($state.isDown === true) {
      $(parent).addClass('scroll-moving');

      const clientX = event.originalEvent.touches ? event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX : event.clientX;

      $(parent).scrollLeft($state.afterDown.clientX + $state.afterDown.scrollLeft - clientX);
    }
  };
}

function scroll (parent) {
  return () => {
    message('scroll');

    if (centering === true) {

      if ($(parent).scrollLeft() === $state.dreamedScrollLeft) {
        message('after scroll centering');

        if (centering === true) {

          if ($(parent).scrollLeft() === $state.dreamedScrollLeft) {
            message('after scroll centering');
          }

        }
      }

    }
  };
}

function up (parent) {
  return (event) => {
    message('up');

    if ($state.isDown === true) {
      $(parent).removeClass('scroll-moving');

      $state.afterUp.clientX = event.originalEvent.changedTouches ? event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX : event.clientX;
      $state.afterUp.scrollLeft = $(parent).scrollLeft();

      if ($state.afterDown.clientX > $state.afterUp.clientX) {
        message(' moving right');

        $state.dreamedScrollLeft = $(parent).scrollLeft() + ($state.afterDown.clientX - $state.afterUp.clientX);
      }

      if ($state.afterUp.clientX > $state.afterDown.clientX) {
        message(' moving left');

        $state.dreamedScrollLeft = $(parent).scrollLeft() - ($state.afterUp.clientX - $state.afterDown.clientX);
      }

      $(parent).animate({ scrollLeft: $state.dreamedScrollLeft, }, duration, 'linear');

      message($state.afterDown, $state.afterUp, $state.dreamedScrollLeft);

      $state.isDown = false;
    }
  };
}

$.fn.extend({
  addScroll: function (i) {
    if (i.centering) {
      centering = i.centering;
    }

    if (i.duration) {
      duration = i.duration;
    }

    if (i.messages) {
      messages = i.messages;
    }

    $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');

    $(this).bind('mousedown touchstart', down(this));
    $(this).bind('mouseleave', leave(this));
    $(this).bind('mousemove touchmove', move(this));
    $(this).bind('scroll', scroll(this));
    $(this).bind('mouseup touchend', up(this));
  },
});
```

Comment: Your bug is with `scroll`, `mousemove` and `touchmove`. And yes.. debounce. It needs a variable (or a [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute to look at?) to know if an animation is already ongoing... Wich needs to be toggled on [`animationEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend).